# How to store ints into std::vector<int> in c++?

Tags: c++

"Working in C++"

I have a UnicodeString that contains some comma seperated integer values e.g:
UnicodeString usCSVs = "3,4,5,6";

I need to store these values in std::vector < int>.
What would be the best possible way of achieving the above functionality.

Regards,
JS

Comment: Sounds like homework to me...

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::istream_iterator` to parse the string. Before that you need to replace all delimiters to spaces.

```
 std::vector<int> myarr;
 std::string int_str = "3,4,5,6";
 std::replace( int_str.begin(), int_str.end(), ',', ' ' );
 std::stringstream in( int_str );
 std::copy( std::istream_iterator<int>(in), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter( myarr ) );
```

For UNICODE version it will look like:

```
 std::wstring int_str = L"3,4,5,6";
 std::replace( int_str.begin(), int_str.end(), L',', L' ' );
 std::wstringstream in( int_str );
 std::copy( std::istream_iterator<int, wchar_t>(in), std::istream_iterator<int, wchar_t>(), std::back_inserter( myarr ) );
```

Comment: niiice, +1 from me, namesake xD

Comment: Than a lot, i am looking for such sort of thing. But i am new to C++ so its difficult for me to understand whole logic. So could you plz answer the following question:

Do we really need to replace ',' with ' '? If yes, then why?
Could you please elaborate the last statement in code?

Could you recommend me some good book or web URL from where i would learn the string manipulations like you code

Comment: Besides, you can write your own `istream_iterator` which will works with `,`, but using `replace` is simpler.

Comment: A good set of C++ Books you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thnx, plz tell me one more thing
what is the meaning of first two arguments in the copy functions, usally it denotes the start and end  of container, but how first two argumnets work in our case?
std::copy( std::istream_iterator<int, wchar_t>(in), std::istream_iterator<int, wchar_t>(), std::back_inserter( myarr ) );

Comment: These arguments are iterators. They are point to the begin and the end of the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the string, first of all. You could iterate through it using std::string::find, that returns a position. You should find the delimiter - ','. Then, get the substring, closed between two commas and use std::stringstream. Done